# mvn serenity:aggregate runs 0 tests and index.html has 0 results however mvn clean verify works and gets results

Tags: rest-assured, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

We have Serenity Cucumber integrated with Maven for REST API automation project running with Junit. Whenever trying to execute the command `mvn serenity:aggregate` results on console shows "Build success' but with 0 requirements loaded and index.html has 0 results and generated under `target/site/serenity`. Whereas if run with the command `mvn clean verify` getting results under the same folder.

pom.xml file of plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.40</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.40</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.totallylazy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>totallylazy</artifactId>
                    <version>1.20</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${basedir}/externalMavenLibrary/totallylazy-1.20.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/site/cucumber-pretty</outputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <classificationFiles>
                            <param>**/*.properties</param>

                        </classificationFiles>
                        <cucumberOutput>${basedir}/target/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <enableFlashCharts>true</enableFlashCharts>
                        <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                        <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Other versions in the pom.xml file:

```
serenity-cucumber: 1.9.35
serenity-rest-assured: 2.0.45

serenity-core: 2.0.45

serenity-junit: 2.2.1
serenity-maven-plugin: 2.0.40
```

Serenity.properties file:

```
serenity.project.name=Test
serenity.console.colors=true
serenity.reports.show.step.details=true
```

Since unable to get report after running mvn serenity:aggregate, missing graphs and other nice features.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to figure out the reason why the command was not working. in pom.xml file, after adding tags and while running the command by giving the report output path, I am able to get the Serenity reports as expected.

updates done:

```
serenity.test.root="com.projectname.backend.core"
serenity.reports.show.step.details=true
serenity.outputDirectory = target/site/reports
```

in pom.xml file: added tags configuration, and the tag has value in RunnerFile.java

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <tags>${tags}</tags>
            </configuration>
```

Also, below dependency versions used:

```
<properties>
<serenity.version>2.2.1</serenity.version>
<serenity.cucumber.version>2.2.0</serenity.cucumber.version>
<serenity.maven.version>2.2.1</serenity.maven.version>
</properties>
```

Command used:

```
 mvn serenity:aggregate -Dserenity.outputDirectory=C:\Users\projectname\target\site\reports
```

Answer (score 1):

I encoutred this problem and my error was that I forgot to name scenario in the feature file. So check this part

Comment: this worked for me, thanks